# URI Routing and Parameter in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am doing a project that when click the 'submit order' button, it will redirect to a successful message page. And the URL is [http://example.com/index.php/Ordering/Order] but I want the URL looks like [http://example.com/index.php/Ordering/Order/1], the number[1] is the id for order which is retrieve from database.
Hope someone can helps me. Thank You.

Route.php:

```
$route['Ordering/Order/(:num)'] = 'Ordering/IdForRoute/$1';
```

Controller:

```
public function IdForRoute(){
    $data['id'] = $this->order->GetId($id);
 if (this->uri->segment(3) === FALSE){
    $data['id'] = 0;
 } else{
    $data['id'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
 }
}
```

Model:

```
public function GetId($id = 0){ 
   if ($id === 0) {
     $query = $this->db->get('order');
     return $query->result_array();
   }

   $query = $this->db->get_where('order', array('id' => $id));
   return $query->row_array();
}
```

Comment: you have missed the `if` statement in your IdForRoute() method, i have updated your question.

Comment: @BearNithi I updated my code, but still not working.

Comment: You should put `$data['id'] = $this->order->GetId($id);`  on else statement with `$data['id'] = $this->uri->segment(3);`

Comment: @Roshan Hi, still not working. Should I put the URL in my view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change your controller to this:

```
public function IdForRoute(){

     if (this->uri->segment(3) === FALSE){
         $id = 0;
         $data['returnedvaluefrommodel'] = $this->order->GetId($id);
      } else{
         $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
         $data['returnedvaluefrommodel'] = $this->order->GetId($id);

     }
 }
```

You can echo `returnedvaluefrommodel` on your view based on the returned value from your model.